# Sum of hyperbolic functions, having problems expressing $\sinh(1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

Using these identities

$\sinh(x+1) - \sinh (x) = (-1+\cosh(1))\sinh(x) + \sinh(1)\cosh(x)$

$\cosh (x+1) - \cosh (x) = (-1+\cosh(1))\cosh(x) + \sinh(1)\sinh(x)$

Express the series $C = \cosh 0 + \cosh 1 + \cosh 2 +\dots+ \cosh n$

```
             $ S = \sinh 0 + \sinh 1 + \sinh 2 + \dots+ \sinh n $
```

In terms of $\cosh(n+1) , \sinh(n+1), \cosh (1)$ and numbers such as $1,2$ etc.

---

This is what I have so far done:

$x = -1, \cosh(0) = \cosh(1)\cosh(-1) + \sinh(1)\sinh(-1)$

$=> \cosh(0) = \cosh^2 (1) - \sinh^2 (1) = 1$

$x=0, \cosh(1) = \cosh (1)$

$x=1, \cosh(2) = \cosh^2 (1) + \sinh^2 (1)$

$\cosh (2)  - \cosh^2 (1) = \cosh ^2 (1) + \sinh^2 (1) - \cosh^(2) (1)$

$=> \cosh(2)  = 2\cosh^2 (1) -1 $

$x = n,\cosh(n+1) = \cosh(1)\cosh(n) + \sinh(n)\sinh(1)$

Also, $\sinh(n+1) = \cosh(1)\sinh(n) + \sinh(1)\cosh(n)$

$\cosh(n+1) + \sinh(n+1) = \cosh(1)[\cosh(n)+\sinh(n)] + \sinh(1)[\sinh(n)+\cosh(n)]$

Trying to solve for $\sinh(1)$.I don't really know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up the left hand side of the prescripted formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sinh(k+1)-\sinh(k)=\sinh(n+1)-\sinh(0)$$
on the one hand, and doing the same with the right-hand side
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sinh(k+1)-\sinh(k)=\sum_{k=0}^n(\cosh(1)-1)\sinh(k)+\sinh(1)\cosh(k)\\=(\cosh(1)-1)S+\sinh(1)C$$
on the other hand.
Do the same with the other formula. You get a system of two equations.
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccccl}
(\cosh(1)-1)S&+&\sinh(1)C&=&\sinh(n+1)\\
\sinh(1)S&+&(\cosh(1)-1)C&=&\cosh(n+1)-1
\end{array}\right.$$
You should be able to conclude.

Comment: i understand the summation of sinh(k+1) - sinh(k) = sinh(n+1), but i don't understand the second set of equations, particularly how S and C fit in. Shouldn't it be the summation of S and not just S by itself? Or is it implied. Also i'm confused how (-1+cosh(1) switched signs

Comment: Sorry about the sign switch. It's fixed now. The second sum is the sum of the right-hand side of the identity you have to use. I just replaced $x$ by $k$ in the sum.

Comment: yep i've got it. Fact that i didn't think of expressing everything in their summation greatly worries me though. Thank you!